# Run SFTP commands in a bash script

Tags: linux, unix, sftp

Hi Community Dwellers,

I have a requirement like this -

1. Need to place csv files from local Linux server to remote linux/windows box.

Actions -

1. We already have passwordless connectivity establish between local and remote boxes.
2. Able to sftp remote server with below command -

   ```
   sftp -o Port=11001 user@xx.xx.xx.xx
   ```
3. Able to copy using put command -

   ```
   put /dir/local/*.csv user@remote:/usr/dir/
   ```
4. Tried to execute above commands in bash script and can only reach till sftp login.
5. Tried running batchfile (in try 1) in the statement as in step 1, can see uploading data, but when you do pwd, folder is empty, no idea where those files are getting written, same with try 2 statement -

try 1 - `sftp -b Test.sh -o Port=11001 user@xxx.xx.xx.xx`

or

try 2 - `sftp -o Port=11001 {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< $'put {local_file_path}'`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of your shell script. Don't give us a paraphrased description of your code.

Comment: It is much easier to automate SSH/SFTP using python or perl and any of the packages available supporting those protocols.